# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var item = list.childNodes[i]._value;
    var RecID = item.RecID;
    var zerocount = 5 - RecID.length;
    var PicZeros = "";
    for (k = 0; k < zerocount; k++)
        PicZeros += "0";
    var url = "/p_" + PicZeros + RecID + "_01.jpg";
}
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I don't understand how to fix it?

Comment: Check if RecID defined.

Comment: What is `_value` here: `list.childNodes[i]._value;` ?

Comment: @YD1m RecID is valid if i dont use RecID.lenght i get RecID value

Comment: @Cherniv list.childNodes[i] a list value from cs file.

Answer (score 2):

Well, at some point, `list.childNodes[i]._value.RecID` is giving you an undefined value.

*That's* the root cause of your problem and you need to fix it.

Perhaps `count` is wrong, perhaps you've populated the list badly, we can't really tell from the code given.

> And, as an aside, I'm almost certain there's better ways to left-pad a string with `0` characters than with a loop. Something like:

```
var url = "/p_" + "00000".substring(RecID.length) + RecID + "_01.jpg";
```

> would be better.

Comment: I get same err : TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @Bip. yes, you have to fix your _real_ problem first, which is the fact that your `RecID` variable is undefined because of some other problem with your list. Once you've fixed that, you can them replace the looping code with something a little cleaner.

Comment: i have no problem without 'RecID.lenght'. if I drop 'RecID.lenght' my code it works successfully

Comment: @Bip, print out (or alert on or output some other way) every value of `url` you set in the loop. I think you'll find that, though you receive no _errors,_ your code is _not_ working okay.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var item = list.childNodes[i]._value;
    var RecID = item.RecID;
    if (RecID){
        var zerocount = 5 - RecID.length;
        var PicZeros = "";
        for (k = 0; k < zerocount; k++)
            PicZeros += "0";
        var url = "/p_" + PicZeros + RecID + "_01.jpg";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that more or less _hides_ the problem, I suspect it would be better to _fix_ it. However, this may well work in the short term so, if that's all you want, go for it :-)

Comment: indeed, but as shown he had no idea about the error, and for us, we have no idea about what he is doing, this could be the right solution could be just hiding, but his sentance `I don't understand how to fix it?` let me add this answer. @paxdiablo

Comment: I have no problem with this answer though I, in my anal retentive nature, would prefer to fix the root cause :-) I can't upvote it (because of that) but I see no reason to downvote since it may well work.

Comment: I just add "0" begining of RecID, if it lenght less than five. RecID always have a value.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
`item.getAttribute('RECID')`
```

OR

place the `<script>` tag AFTER the `<body>`

like

```
<html> 
<body>
 </body>
<script>
</script>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are we reading the same question? :-) If that is indeed the correct answer, it might help to state _why._

Comment: because the 'list' or 'item' whose length you are trying to find out, that must exists when you are calling the function. so, you must call the function after the `body`

Comment: @Rhea Thanks for answer but its not my answer